# Assign a array of indexes as an object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexing, javascript-objects

I have an assignment which i need to sole but i am really stuck and can't make a progress. The assignment consist in an array of elements like this

```
const appleHolderLine = ['Rome', 'Ambrosia', 'Rome', 'RedDelicious', 'Akane','RedDelicious', 'SweeTango', 'RedDelicious', 'RedDelicious', 'Opal', 'Winesap', 'RedDelicious', 'Empire', 'RedDelicious', 'Liberty'];
```

Firstly it is needed to declare a variable `lineCount` which count for every element of the array and a reference to an object called `appleMap`.

Than the challenge consist in looping through the array and the elements of the array would be the object keys with no duplicates and the values would be an array of idexes of the specific element place of the array. To give an example how it should look like:

Example:

```
const appleHolderLine = ['GreenApples', 'RedDelicious','OrangeApples', 'PurpleApples', 'RedDelicious']
console.log (lineCount, appleMap)
```

Should Log:

```
5, {'GreenApples':[0], 'RedDelicious': [1,4], 'OrangeApples':[2], 'PurpleApples': [3]}
```

My progress so far

```
var lineCount = 0;
var appleMap = {};
for (let i = 0; i < appleHolderLine.length; i++){
    lineCount++;
    // if element in the array exist in the array  
    appleMap[appleHolderLine[i]] = [i];
}
```

Could you give me a hint of how to solve this, i am really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can create an empty array the first time and keep pushing like below

```
var lineCount = 0;
var appleMap = {};
for (let i = 0; i < appleHolderLine.length; i++){
  lineCount++;
  if(!appleMap[appleHolderLine[i]])
    appleMap[appleHolderLine[i]] = []
  appleMap[appleHolderLine[i]].push(i);

 }
```

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce` which is a more advanced construct javascript provides. Please refer to answer by CodeManiac below for the same.
The above answer is to clarify the basic idea and hint on how you could think

Also, lineCount can be obtained by using `appleHolderLine.length` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra variable ( Line count ) here, simply loop over the value use, use the index to access value, check if there's nothing present for that key then just initialize it with empty array, push index to the key in each iteration

```js
const appleHolderLine = ['GreenApples', 'RedDelicious','OrangeApples', 'PurpleApples', 'RedDelicious']
var appleMap = {};
for (let i = 0; i < appleHolderLine.length; i++){
  if(!appleMap[appleHolderLine[i]]){
    appleMap[appleHolderLine[i]] = []
  }
  appleMap[appleHolderLine[i]].push(i);
}

console.log(appleMap)
```

You can simply use `reduce`

```js
const appleHolderLine = ['GreenApples', 'RedDelicious','OrangeApples', 'PurpleApples', 'RedDelicious']

let final = appleHolderLine.reduce((op,inp,i)=>{
  op[inp] = op[inp] || []
  op[inp].push(i)
  return op
},{})


console.log(final)
```

Line count is simply same as length of array, `let lineCount = appleHolderLine.length`

Answer (score -1):

I suppose, the shortest answer is the functional one.

```js
const appleHolderLine = ['GreenApples', 'RedDelicious','OrangeApples', 'PurpleApples', 'RedDelicious']

result = appleHolderLine.reduce((a,c,i) => { if(a[c]) a[c].push(i); else a[c]=[i]; return a; }, {})

console.log(result)
```

But I am not sure that you are expected to deliver a functional solution. Still, you might find it useful. The idea is that the `reduce` method starts with an empty object and iterates through the array. In each iteration, it checks if the current element `c` is already a field of the accumulator `a`. If so adds its index `i` to the specific field, if not, initializes the field with the current element as name and the index as a single-element array as value.